# Synchronized в данном случае (Java)

Tags: java, synchronized, suspend

```
package StopAndResume;

public class NewThread implements Runnable {
    String name;
    Thread t;
    boolean flag;
    NewThread(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        t = new Thread(this, name);
        System.out.println("New Thread "  + t);
        flag = false;
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            for(int i = 15; i > 0; i--)
            {
                System.out.println(name + ": " + i);
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                synchronized (this) // ЗАЧЕМ ЭТО НУЖНО В ДАННОМ СЛУЧАЕ?
                {
                    while(flag)
                    {
                        wait();
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Interrupted !");
        }
        System.out.println("Finish!!!!!");
    }
    synchronized void mysuspend()
    {
        flag = true;
    }
    synchronized void myresume()
    {
        flag = false;
        notify();
    }
}


        class Demo{
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                NewThread obj1 = new NewThread("F_I_R_S_T");
                NewThread obj2 = new NewThread("S_E_C_O_N_D");
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                    obj1.mysuspend();
                    System.out.println(obj1.name + " is suspended!");
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                    obj1.myresume();
                    System.out.println(obj1.name + " is resumed!");
                    obj2.mysuspend();
                    System.out.println(obj2.name + " is suspended!");
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                    obj2.myresume();
                    System.out.println(obj2.name + " is resumed!");
                }catch (InterruptedException e){
                    System.out.println("Interrupted!");
                }
                try{
                    obj1.t.join();
                    obj2.t.join();
                }catch (InterruptedException e){
                    System.out.println("Interrupted!");
                }


            }
        }
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться , зачем нам нужна эта синхронизация в данном случае ? Как я ожидал , когда obj1 входит в этот метод и вызывает ожидание , то он должен блокировать вход obj2 так как он находиться в этом мониторе до тех пор пока не пробудится. Но obj2 не блокируется. Так вот ПОЧЕМУ obj2 не блокируется? И зачем нужна была эта синхронизация?

Comment: у вас 2 потока вообще не могут влиять друг на друга, нет общих переменных. Синхронизация же нужна чтобы класс получился `thread-safe`

Comment: но разве цикл while в данном случае не общий? Разве , когда один поток находится в этом цикле , другой поток может иметь к этому циклу доступ ?

Comment: что значит *общий*? каждый поток имеет свой `this`, так почему захват (блокировка) в `synchronized` одного должна как-то влять на другой

Comment: Все , только понял . Спасибо. Но , почему выдаётся ошибка если убрать synchronised ?